Imported Packages :com.day.cq.wcm.api,version=[1.31,2) -- Cannot be resolved
I am facing a  issue after creating the AEM project using the archetype 47.
The project build successfully and deployed perfectly and somehow the osgi bundle is not "Active" because of below issue in
bold:com.day.cq.wcm.api,version=\[1.31,2) -- Cannot be resolved org.apache.sling.api.request,version=\[2.7,3) -- Cannot be resolved   Maven Dependency:

<dependency>
    <artifactId>cq-wcm-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.14.6</version>
    <groupId>com.day.cq.wcm</groupId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


Wich service pack has been installed? I checked my instance and this contains 5.14.16

May be the installed service pack and installed uber.jar are not compatible together.

I faced a similar issue and found that the documentation provided a clear solution. you can check it out here it helped me to resolve the problem, and i hope it works for you too. Good luck! Hope it helps!
